# cutting text through a background vector in illustrator problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator

1) I downloaded a vector background and would like to cut text through it.

2) I wrote text on it.

3) converted this text to outlines.
[image]

4) selected text and background.

5) used pathfinder tool "minus front" option.

When I do this the background is converted to a black square as shown in picture.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to cut text through a random background i.e when coverted to png, the text area is transparent?

Answer (score 4):

You can create an opacity mask to achieve that.

I assume the background vector image to be cut is in a group. If not, then make sure you group it before continuing.

1. Type some black text over the image you want to cut out
2. With the Selection tool (V) select both the background group, and the text
3. Open the Appearance panel, and click on the Opacity
4. Click *Make Mask*
5. Deselect the *Clip* option.

I have also added a beige shape in the example below, so you can see that the blue background is actually cut out by the opacity mask.

[image]

The beauty of this method is that it's non destructive. The text inside the mask is still editable. You can enter the mask by clicking on the mask thumbnail in the opacity panel, edit the text, move it etc, and exit the mask by clicking back on the object thumbnail.